# UK spouse, South African wife, Schengen visa

Tags: schengen

There seems to be conflicting info if you are a non-EU or UK citizen but are married to one. What are the European laws (that even the Embassies and airline staff get wrong apparently) and requirements if you are with your UK partner and want to travel to Europe with them? Is a visa needed? Or is just a marriage certificate and return travel ticket sufficient?

Comment: Where are the two of you normally resident?

Comment: I am in South africa & he is in Scotland.We dont live together presently as we still have gruelling spouse visa documents to get together etc.So he lives in Scotland & I live in Cape town but am going over on a holiday visa for 5 months to UK to spend time with my husband & we might want to do trip to Europe

Answer (score 3):

As you are the spouse of an EU national but do not hold an EU residence card, you will need an entry visa to enter the Schengen states.

An entry visa can certainly be issued to you at the border, but there is a small possibility of it being denied if border officials are not satisfied with your paperwork. You will in any case be subject to delays and possible questioning as your documents are verified.

For that reason, it's *advisable* to simply apply for a Schengen visa in advance; given your husband's status as an EU citizen, you will be exempt from the visa fee, and will generally need to provide your travel documents and marriage certificate as supporting documentation for your application (you will usually not need to provide proof of hotel reservations, health insurance etc.). Your visa should be processed within 15 days, and will allow you smooth entry and transit within the Schengen area.

Official EU guidance on this topic is available [here](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-family/index_en.htm). The documents required for an entry visa for non-EU family members do vary slightly by country, so make sure you contact the consulate of the Schengen country you want before you apply.

Happy travels!

Comment: Thank you so much for the most informative answer.Helps a lot.

Comment: @Dee Glad you found it useful, and that I could help!

Comment: "An entry visa can certainly be issued to you at the border": this is true, but it won't be possible to reach the border by airplane because no airline will board someone in these circumstances.  "You will in any case be subject to delays and possible questioning as your documents are verified": we've had a couple of reports here of people crossing both ways between the UK and the Schengen area by train or ferry with fairly little trouble.  I suppose there were in fact "delays" and "questioning," but they seem to have been negligible.

Comment: "I suppose there were in fact "delays" and "questioning," but they seem to have been negligible." It's good that the people you were referring to were not subject to this; however, these types of delays are relatively common, and even online, you can find quite a few examples of what I was referring to. At the end of the day, border officers have a fair level of discretionary power to make life difficult for you; whether or not they choose to exercise it is a different story.